# Let $f(x)=\dfrac{2x}{x+3} \ \ , \ \ g(x)=\dfrac{x+2}{x-4}$ Now what is Domain of function $f \circ g $ .

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let $f(x)=\dfrac{2x}{x+3}  \ \ , \ \ g(x)=\dfrac{x+2}{x-4}$

Now what is Domain of  function $f \circ g $ .

---

My try :

We know that 
$$D_{f \circ g }=\{x\in D_g \ ; \ g(x)\in D_f\}$$

$$D_g=\mathbb{R}/\{4\}$$

$$D_f=\mathbb{R}/\{-3\}$$

Now what ?

Comment: Hint...Solve $g(x)=-3$

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the places where $g$ is undefined, $f\circ g$ is undefined when $f$ is undefined at $g(x)$. This amounts to finding the place(s) where $g(x)=-3$, since $f(x)$ is undefined only at $x=-3$.